# Python assign a variable use if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to assign a variable when `if` statement is true. What's wrong with this assignment?

> b = 1 if  3 > 2

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    b = 1 if 3 > 2
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `if 3 > 2:b = 1` ?

Comment: That syntax only works if you have an else `b = 1 if 3 > 2 else 90`

Answer (score 1):

You need an else in case your condition fails.

```
b = 1 if 3>2 else 0
```